# What is SymantecSanctionsServer in Firefox build?

Tags: firefox

Building a browser (icecat/firefox) from mozilla's source an executable name `SymantecSanctionsServer` was created.

What is `SymantecSanctionsServer`? 
Is this related to the "snake-oil" company?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have the source code, you can search in it for this string and even read the corresponding source code. You should find it in the "[TLS unit tests](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/security/manager/ssl/tests/unit/tlsserver/cmd)" directory, along with several other 'server' binaries.

These binaries are compiled as part of Mozilla's automated testing suite (not part of the final binary releases), and their purpose is to act as a TLS server imitating some specific (mis)configuration. The tests make sure the browser reacts to such a server the way it's meant to.

This particular test uses Symantec-issued TLS certificates which are [gradually distrusted](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2018/03/12/distrust-symantec-tls-certificates/) by browsers, and is used to check that nobody accidentally broke the "time-gated distrust" logic (certificates issued before date X are supposed to still be accepted, but new ones are not).

In this context, Symantec wasn't exactly a "snake-oil" company, and the test has nothing to do with e.g. its antivirus software – the Symantec web CA business started out as an [acquisition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg#%22Resistance_is_futile%22) of VeriSign and Thawte, two of the oldest (and originally "most reputable") certificate authorities. Unfortunately it [went bad](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA:Symantec_Issues) over the years.